# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{(1+x)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I have to determine whether or not the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{(1+x)^n}$$
converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.

I attempted to use Weierstrass' M-Test, by finding the maxima of each $a_n$ which must exist by the maximum value theorem. The maxima turned out to be at $\dfrac{1}{n-1}$, and to be equal to $\dfrac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$. The sum of these terms diverges, and hence I can't use Weierstrass' M-Test.

Now, I'm thinking of using Dini's Theorem since $[0,1]$ is compact, and seting $f_n(x)$ to be the $n$-th partial sum gives us a monotonic increasing sequence. So if I can find the pointiwse limit of this sequence, and verify it is continuous, I will be done.

Is this the right track? If it is, how would I compute the series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as $N\to \infty$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{x}{(1+x)^n}=1-\frac{1}{(1+x)^{N}}\to 
\begin{cases}0&\text{if $x=0$,}\\
1&\text{if $x>0$.}\end{cases}$$
So the pointwise limit function is not a continuous in $[0,a)$ with $a>0$. What may we conclude about the uniform convergence over such interval?
What happens over $[a,b]$ with $0<a<b$?

Comment: I see, so there is no uniform convergence. But how do we obtain that expansion?

Comment: The series is geometric with $r=1/(1+x)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Answer (score 1):

For $0<x\le1$, the series converges to
$$\frac{x}{1+x}\frac1{1-\frac1{1+x}}=1$$
(geometric series).
For $x=0$ it converges to $0$. Is the limit continuous?